# How to create inverted cone graph using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, core-plot

I tried to google this but could not find anything.

Do you have any idea how to create inverted cone graph like this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that there is any direct API which does this. But you can try to draw or plot it using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html or try using `CoreGraphics` at more basic level to draw something like what you want. Hope this helps you.

Comment: If you use UIWebView then you could use something different from Objective-C to active your goal (except of flash of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is any direct API which does this.

But you can try to draw or plot it using

[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

or

try using `CoreGraphics` Framework at more basic level to draw something like what you want.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have not tried it. We are going to avoid creating the graph. In our case, we have a site which displays the graph. We will just show the graph in webview instead.